# Altium: how to export netlist with net class data from Altium?

Tags: altium

I am testing Altium for some simple electrical harness design. Now I am trying to generate a report for manual wiring and would like to have typical netlist data (nets and pins) together with net class in a spreadsheet. I plan to use net classes to define wire data - part number, maybe mounting directives, etc.

The only netlist format that I found to contain this data is EDIF, but parsing that in to a spreadsheet is a task not for the fainthearted.

PCB editor has some more output features, but I have yet to try everything out.

So, how to export netlist with net class data from Altium?

Comment: A non automatic way is to use the PCB list and hand copy the information, I don't know if this will work for net classes. I do see classes on the list.

Comment: Same is possible in Sch editor too. Info is there and can be copied to clipboard.